# Where on the filesystem are NetworkManager WiFi connections stored on Fedora 32 Workstation (GNOME)?

Tags: fedora, wifi, configuration, networkmanager

I'm trying to manually edit a WiFi connection I added via the gnome-shell WiFI interface. Resources I find online seem to indicate they are stored in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`, however in my case this directory is empty (and I definitely have saved connections). Where might I find these connections in Fedora 32 Workstation (GNOME)?

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there something wrong with the question?

Answer (score 2):

`nmcli -f all connection` lists also the filename.

In practice, it will be on Fedora 32 in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`. That depends on the "main.plugins" setting (see `man NetworkManager.conf`). Fedora 33 will change that default location...

Comment: Also `nmcli -f NAME,FILENAME connection`.